# What is the point of a Quine program?

Tags: quine

I just recently learned about Quine programs today in my CS class. I understand that they are programs meant to output there own source code, or "self-reproduce". But what I don't get is, besides being a good test of coding ability and logic, whats the point? Can these types of programs be used in real life situations or are they simply for fun?

Are they applicable to the real word?

Comment: What's the point of art?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used in programming viruses that can swarm over a computer or a network, being able to self-replicate themselves. But this is vastly more sophisticated than writing a simple Quine.

Answer (score 2):

Quines are "just for fun" but fun in this case is related to learning! Understanding and thinking about quines helps you tease apart in your mind the difference between textual representation and meaning, which is an important distinction that can be hard to describe or understand directly.